# dynamically change the combo box store in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have two combo boxes. When select the first combo box's first element the second combo box's elements need to change accordingly.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    name: 'type',
    store: 'type',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    queryMode: 'local',


}, {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'State',
    name: 'state',
    store: state,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    queryMode: 'local',
}
```

So if I select first element of type combo box the state combo box need to have the element which are in state. Otherwise It should have to contain the elements in states.

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    data: [{
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'A'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'B'
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'name': 'C'
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'name': 'D'
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'name': 'E'
        }
    ]
});

var state = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    data: [{
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'A'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'B'
        }
    ]

});
```

That means my second combo box's store part need to be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a change listener on the first `combobox` and use the `bindStore` function on the second `combobox` to bind the correct store:

```
listeners: {
    change: function(combo, nV) {
        if(nV=="A") combo.nextSibling().bindStore(state);
        if(nV=="B") combo.nextSibling().bindStore(states);
    }
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eoh

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use [`combo.setStore(store)`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#method-setStore).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eoi)**, I have created a demo using [`combo`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html). I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //Store Type
        Ext.define('StoreType', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.storetype',
            fields: ['text', 'value'],
            data: [{
                text: 'Store1',
                value: 'store1'
            }, {
                text: 'Store2',
                value: 'store2'
            }]
        });
        //Store 1
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'store1',
            fields: ['text', 'value'],
            data: [{
                text: 'A',
                value: 'A'
            }]
        });

        //Store 2
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'store2',
            fields: ['text', 'value'],
            data: [{
                text: 'B',
                value: 'B'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Combobox store change ',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Select Store',
                store: {
                    type: 'storetype'
                },
                queryMode: 'local',
                listeners: {
                    select: function (cmp, record) {
                        var combo = cmp.up('panel').down('#myStore');

                        if (combo.isDisabled()) {
                            combo.setDisabled(false);
                        }
                        combo.reset();
                        combo.setStore(record[0].get('value'));
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                itemId: 'myStore',
                fieldLabel: 'Select value',
                disabled: true
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a change event to your first combo box. Load the store data in that function for second combo box by passing the selected value of first combobox.

```
     {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Type',
        name: 'type',
        store: 'type',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        queryMode: 'local',
        listeners: {
         change: function(this,newVal,oldVal,eOpts){
           var store = Ext.getStore('state');
            store.load( 
            params:  {
                /* parameters to pass*/
            },
            callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                /* perform operations on the records*/
            });
         }
       }
     }
```